# adding a div tag over a slideshow

Tags: html, css

How we can add a `div` tag over a slideshow like in the following link

http://www.hellofresh.com/

Here the `div` with title "DISCOVER THE  JOY OF COOKING " is placed over a slideshow.

How might I do this?

Comment: What have you done? Use something like Firebug (a plugin for Firefox) to inspect each element, its style classes, z-index...., there is nothing special about it.

Comment: if you are using chrome, right click on the webpage & click "Inspect element". You can find the DOM elements & their CSS, Javascript etc. Similarly, in Firefox, you can use an extension called Firebug which is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can do something like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/YgpqX/ ):

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>​

​.div1 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aa5;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  background: #5aa;
}
​
```

Or ( http://jsfiddle.net/YgpqX/1/ )

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>​

.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aa5;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -200px;
  background: #5aa;
}
```

​And if your block in html should be earlier then slider block, then use `z-index: 9999;` to get it up.

And also abolute position:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
​
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aa5;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #5aa;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, welcome to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (oops; this isn't your first question!). The key to placing your `div` over the slideshow (or over any other element) is using **absolute positioning**. Absolute positioning enables you to specify the exact position for an element instead of leaving it with the flow of the document. If you take a look at [your example website](http://www.hellofresh.com/)'s CSS, you can see that the `div` that has "Discover the joy of cooking" is styled basically like this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

`top` and `left` act somehow like `x` and `y` in a 2-dimensional grid system, except that the origin is placed differently. `top: 0px;` pulls the `div` up and `left: 0px;` pulls the `div` left, so all-in-all, it's placed on the upper-left corner.

To achieve the effect of the translucent black, you use the `opacity` property. `opacity: 0.5;` means that the `div` is half-opaque, while `opacity: 0;` means it's not visible at all. Your favorite value might be something like `opacity: 0.7;` -- anything in the range `0...1`.

The last piece here is to tell the browser that the `div` should be **over** the slideshow, not behind it. To do that, use the `z-index` property. `z-index` specifies the relative "stack order" of elements. So if you want your `div` to be over the slideshow, style it with `z-index: 5;` while styling the slideshow with `z-index: 1;`, for instance.

Hope that helped at all!

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `opacity` property in CSS

This is some basic info on this one [W3schools Css opaque](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Answer (score 0):

They are accomplishing this effect using CSS Positioning.  Basically they are absolutely positioning the discover the joy of cooking block over the slide show.  You can use z-index on the absolute position div to bring it over the relative position (slideshow) div.  Basically you need to use a combination of position and z-index.  I have a basic example of the CSS/HTML here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jqVAe/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    Scrolling sideshow goes here.  Scrolling sideshow goes here.  Scrolling sideshow goes here.  Scrolling sideshow goes here.  Scrolling sideshow goes here. Scrolling sideshow goes here.Scrolling sideshow goes here.
    <div id="over-slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #slideshow{
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        background: green;    
    }

#over-slideshow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;    
}
```

This provides a basic structure in which to put your slideshow.  I would recommend finding a good slide show plugin and not trying to reinvent that functionality.  I'm sure there are plenty of Jquery (Javascript Framework) plugins that will accomplish this task for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `position: absolute` and `z-index`. z index is used to align a layer over or under a layer. You may go through;

**[Lesson 15: Layer on layer with z-index (Layers)](http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php)**, **[Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index)**, and **[A Detailed Look at the z-index CSS Property](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-detailed-look-at-the-z-index-css-property/)**